# replace href with angular regular expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, regex, ionic-framework

I'm looking for a filter to replace "href" in a TextEntity of an API. The "text" can  contains 3 different kind of URLs. After the replacement I want to open the corrected URLs in a new separate window.

I receive from the textvalue the following information:

```
1. <a href="http://someurl.tdl">link</a> - this is an example for a all kind of external links. Can be mysite.com/mypage.html or any other valid url. Like everything with a http://, https://, ftp:// in the startof the url.
2. <a href="singpage.html">internal page</a> - Can includes all other files. like mypdf.pdf or mydoc.doc or other stuff, but without http://mydomain.tdl
3. <a href="mailto: mymail@domain.tdl">mymail@domain.tdl</a>
```

I tried something but it doesn't work.

```
.filter('parseText', function ($sce, $sanitize) {
var mydomain = 'http://www.mydomain.tdl';
return function (text) {
    var newStringUrlReplace = $sanitize(text).replace('href="','href="'+mydomain);
    var regex = /href="([\S]+)"/g;
    var newString = newStringUrlReplace.replace(regex, "class=\"externalURL\" onClick=\"cordova.InAppBrowser.open('$1', '_blank', 'location=yes')\"");
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(newString);
    }
});
```

I need this output the "text" ran went through the filter:

```
1. <a href="http://someurl.tdl" class="externalURL" onClick="cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://someurl.tdl', '_blank', 'location=yes')">link</a>
2. <a href="http://www.mydomain.tdl/singpage.html" onClick="cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://www.mydomain.tdl/singpage.html', '_blank', 'location=yes')">internal page</a>
3. <a href="mailto: mymail@domain.tdl">mymail@domain.tdl</a>
```

To make it easier to understand:

I need a function which turns this types of URLs.

```
<a href="http://someurl.tdl/whichcanincludeanything.html?bar=foo">URL TO A  EXTERNAL PAGE</a>

<a href="singpage.html">internal page of the CMS</a>
```

into

```
<a href="http://someurl.tdl/whichcanincludeanything.html?bar=foo" class="externalURL" onClick="cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://someurl.tdl/whichcanincludeanything.html?bar=foo', '_blank', 'location=yes')">URL TO A  EXTERNAL PAGE</a>

<a href="http://www.mydomain.tdl/singpage.html" onClick="cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://www.mydomain.tdl/singpage.html', '_blank', 'location=yes')">internal page</a>
```

Comment: Well, are you sure is it the **expected** result? This makes no sense with the code that you already have..

Comment: i guess my code just extend the a href with the class and the onclick event... and i tried also to replace the href. the href which has not a valid domain (the intern url) in it.

Comment: What I mean is: why the 1st. and the 3rd. *urls* (in your expected result) won't change the `href`??

Comment: the first one is working, but the second and thrid is not - the second is the link without the domain, i treid to replace it in newStringUrl and the thrid one is not handled in any way by my code and i have also not a single idea how to handle it.

Comment: Well, again I can't get your logic. In the 1st. example you have: `<a href="http://someurl.tdl">` and you **didn't** want to change it (according to your expected result) -- the same for the 3rd. example. However in your 2nd. example, you want to change the `href`. What's the logic of it? Why not all the 3 should be change? What's the difference between them?

Comment: in the first - i have <a href="http://someurl.tdl">link</a> and i want to change it to:
<a href="http://someurl.tdl" class="externalURL" onClick="cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://someurl.tdl', '_blank', 'location=yes')">link</a>
2. Example is <a href="singpage.html">internal page</a> and i want to change it to <a href="http://www.mydomain.tdl/singpage.html" onClick="cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://www.mydomain.tdl/singpage.html', '_blank', 'location=yes')">internal page</a>

Comment: I mean you didn't want to change the `href` attribute in the 1st. and 3rd. examples, but in the 2nd. I'm trying to know why...

Comment: oh ok - the first url is an extern url to somepage, like google.com and the second url ist an internal page of the website the api came from. so i need on the second case to extend the href with the orignal domain of the website.

Comment: let me know if my solution is what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version *working* based on your *original* `code`:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
    .filter('parseText', parseText);

  function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.array = [
      '<a href="http://someurl.tdl">link</a>',
      '<a href="singpage.html">internal page</a>',
      '<a href="mailto: mymail@domain.tdl">mymail@domain.tdl</a>',
      '<a href="http://someurl.tdl/whichcanincludeanything.html?bar=foo">URL TO A  EXTERNAL PAGE</a>',
      '<a href="singpage.html">internal page of the CMS</a>'
    ];
  }

  function parseText($sce) {
    var myDomain = 'http://www.mydomain.tdl/';
    var externalRegex = /([http|https|ftp]+:\/\/[^"]*)/g;
    var internalRegex = /(href=)"([^"]*)/g;
    return function(input) {
      if (!input) return;
      if (input.indexOf('mailto: ') !== -1) return input;
      var url = '';
      if (externalRegex.test(input)) {
        url = input.replace(externalRegex, '$1" class="externalURL" onClick="cordova.InAppBrowser.open(\'$1\', \'_blank\', \'location=yes\')');
      } else {
        url = input.replace(internalRegex, '$1 ' + myDomain + '$2' + ' class="externalURL" onClick="cordova.InAppBrowser.open(\'' + myDomain + '$2' + '\', \'_blank\', \'location=yes\')');
      }
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(url);
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" >

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p ng-repeat="url in array track by $index">
    <span ng-bind-html="url | parseText"></span>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: at first - thank you, but that was not what i was looking for - in my case the text is not an array, its a string and your solution would only work with domains wich would end with "tdl" but an extern url could be also, "http://stackoverlow.com/questions/3888... /somepage.html".

Comment: @Marq, well, you said: "The "text" can contains 3 kinds of urls.", I work based on what you said. Also it was just an example man. The filter works with everything. Edit your question posting all the urls that you have and what is the expected result, please.

Comment: sry, i tried my best - but im very new to javascript and also to stackoverflow :()

Comment: @Marq, have you checked it now?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, 
well i have a solution now...

```
.filter('parseText', function ($sce, $sanitize) {
return function ( text ) {
var mydomain = 'http://www.mydomain.tdl';
text = $sanitize(text);
var source,sear,repl;
var newString;
var regex = /href="([\S]+)"/g;
var extMatch = /http|https|\/\//g;
var mtMatch = /mailto:/g;

var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = text;
var aList = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
var aListNew = new Array();
var href,t;

if(aList.length>0){

for(var i = 0; i<aList.length; i++ ){
  href = aList[i].getAttribute("href");
  t = aList[i].outerHTML;
  t = $sanitize(t);

  if(href.match(extMatch)!=null){
    newString = t.replace(regex, "class=\"externalURL\" onClick=\"cordova.InAppBrowser.open('$1', '_blank', 'location=yes')\"");

  } else if(href.match(mtMatch)!=null){
    newString = t;
  } else{
    newString = t.replace(regex, "class=\"externalURL\" onClick=\"cordova.InAppBrowser.open('"+mydomain+"$1', '_blank', 'location=yes')\"");
  }

  source = text;
  sear = t;
  repl = newString;
  text = text.replace(t,newString);
     }   
 }
 return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
     };
 });
```